# Using array.filter() method on an array passed as a function argument

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am going through the FreeCodeCamp "Falsy Bouncer" challenge. I have to remove all the falsy values from an array. I already know that the simplest solution would be to filter Boolean, but I wonder if it's possible to solve the problem this way.

I looked up the arr.filter() method on different websites, but in those examples a variable with an array comes before the function. In my case the array I have to operate on comes as an argument of the function. So I don't really understand where do I put this line: `var result = arr.filter(bouncer)`.  If it goes outside the function - then it returns `arr is not defined`. If it goes in the function it returns - `arr.filter is not a function`.

Here is my code:

```
 function bouncer(arr) {
    // Where do I put this line?   
    var result = arr.filter(bouncer);
    return arr !== false, null, 0, NaN, undefined,"";
  }

  bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

So how is the array.filter() method used if the array is given as an argument of a function?

Comment: Arguments *are* just variables. `var result = arr.filter(bouncer);` is close but you shouldn't be passing the `bouncer` function to filter, you're creating a recursive loop that will never finish

Comment: Do you want to keep `"ate"` in the result array or do you want to keep numbers only?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep "ate" too. I only need to filter out the falsy elements: false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the method wrong, and you can't check for multiple things separated by a comma. The correct way of doing what you want would be

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(v => !!v);
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]))
```

Comment: That's not correct @Andreas, the isNaN check would not be covered, "ate" would stay in the array. But I agree you could simplify it to what I have edited in the answer

Comment: Why should "ate" be removed? The values in the "comparison" part are all [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Unless there is no further definition on the `NaN` part I see no reason for the `isNaN()` check and hence would go with ibrahims solution.

Comment: @Andreas after reading the challenge's description I admit you're right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `bouncer` to be the function that you use to return the filtered array then use this:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(e => !!e);
}

var result = bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9, NaN]);
console.log(result);
```

And if you want `bouncer` to be the callback that you want to pass to `filter`, then use this:

```js
function bouncer(elem) {
  return !!elem;
}

var result = [7, "ate", "", false, 9, NaN].filter(bouncer);
console.log(result);
```

**Note:** `!!someVariable` will implicitly transform `someVariable` into its equivalent boolean value.

Comment: Your filter allows NaN's

Comment: @baao No it doesn't!

Comment: Click on run code snippet and look at "ate" in the resulting array. What but a NaN is that?

Comment: @baao I think you missinterprett the question! He wants to filter the thruthy and falsy values!

Comment: @baao You're so mistaken my friend!

Comment: after reading the challenge's description I admit you're right.